# Do 'for' loop support in gnuplot 4.0 version?

Tags: gnuplot

I am getting error: `Invalid expression` while using for loop

Here is the data file:

**test.dat**

```
# C1 C2 C3
23 b 323
23 g 54
23 a 11
23 c 1
23 d 0
23 e 397
23 f 40
24 b 23
24 g 24
24 a 113
24 c 12
24 d 10
24 e 7
24 f 50
```

**In Unix, with gnuplot 4.0:**

```
gnuplot> plot for [s in 'a b c d e f g'] sprintf("<(grep '%s' test.dat)", s) using 1:3 with lines

                   ^
         invalid expression
```

I have 4.0 version installed in our office server and we are supposed to work on it.

When I try the same command in the local windows machine with gnuplot 5.0 , I am getting a different error:

```
gnuplot> plot \
       > for [s in 'a b c d e f g'] \
       > sprintf("<(grep '%s' testdata1.dat)", s) \
       > using 1:3 with lines            
         warning: Skipping unreadable file "<(grep 'a' testdata1.dat)"
         warning: Skipping unreadable file "<(grep 'b' testdata1.dat)"
         warning: Skipping unreadable file "<(grep 'c' testdata1.dat)"
         warning: Skipping unreadable file "<(grep 'd' testdata1.dat)"
         warning: Skipping unreadable file "<(grep 'e' testdata1.dat)"
         warning: Skipping unreadable file "<(grep 'f' testdata1.dat)"
         warning: Skipping unreadable file "<(grep 'g' testdata1.dat)"
         No data in plot
```

Here the for loop works, but redirecting of the file content to sprintf do not work.

*The expected result is that for every value of s, the grepped contents of **test.dat** redirects to **sprintf**, which is used as data source for plotting resulting in multiple overlapped graphs.*

In this example,

For `s=='a'`, the output should be

```
#C1 C2 C3
23 a 11
24 a 113
```

But, it seems to be the piping is not working in windows. Unfortunately, I can't test whether the scrip works or not either in Unix or windows.

Please suggest.

Comment: Indeed, `plot for` was introduced in version 4.4. On Windows you can use pipes, but not `grep`.

Comment: Well, version 4.0 is 11 years old ;) If your values you iterate over don't change, you can write them out like `plot '< grep "a" testdata1.dat', '< grep "b" testdata1.dat, ...`